# Thread-safe logger for Tcl

Tags: multithreading, logging, tcl

I need a logging library for my multi-threaded Tcl aplication. Can I use standard `logger` package? If I can, what restrictions are applied in multi-threading environment?

I'd like to share logging *services* among the threads, if possible.

Thanks

Comment: http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/logger.html also take a look at http://code.activestate.com/lists/tcl-core/10866/

Comment: First link refers to some custom logger which is too poorly described to use. Second link refers to standard logger library I mentioned in my question. Is it thread-safe indeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl threads do not share data (unless you explicitly use certain facilities from the Thread package) and instead are communicating via message passing.  So it seems like the way to go would be to setup a dedicated "logger" thread and just queue logging messages into it from the worker threads.

Otherwise the point of contention will probably be somewhere in the OS resource used by the logger to actually write data.

**Update** Okay, here's a working sketch of what I actually proposed to implement:

```
package require Tcl 8.5
package require Thread

proc make_worker_thread {logger_id body} {
  set newbody [list set ::logger $logger_id]
  append newbody \n {
    proc ::log {severity msg} {
      global logger
      thread::send $logger [list ::log $severity $msg]
    }
  } \n $body
  thread::create $newbody
}

set logger [thread::create {
  package require logger

  proc log {severity msg} {
    puts "hey, that's it: ($severity) $msg"
  }

  puts "logger thread created: [thread::id]"

  thread::wait
}]

for {set i 0} {$i < 3} {incr i} {
  make_worker_thread $logger {
    proc post_msg {} {
      log notice "A message from [thread::id]"
        after 1000 ::post_msg
    }

    puts "worker thread created: [thread::id]"

    after 1000 ::post_msg

    thread::wait
  }
}

vwait forever
```

This code creates one logger thread and four worker threads each of which posts a message to the logger thread once per second. The code runs until manually interrupted. The logger thread just simple-mindedly outputs the message it was passed to the console, but as someone else in this thread already mentioned, you could probably use the "logger" package from Tcllib, if you need fancy stuff like facilities.

To reiterate my points:

- The logger package itself does not presumably know anything about threading.
- Tcl threads are well-separated and usually communicate via message passing.
- Hence create a thread for the logger and teach worker threads send messages to it; therefore working threads are not concerned with how logger is implemented.

P.S. In the worker threads, you can use `[thread::send -async ...]` to make sending log messages fully asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds to be a solution. Do you know any existing and robust implementations of such a dedicated logging thread?

Comment: @Andrey, why would you need that? It seems to be a no-brainer: basically you create a new thread and then in it you load that "logger" package, bootstrap it and then enter the event loop.  Other threads use `thread::send` on that thread's id.  Start from http://wiki.tcl.tk/Thread

Comment: I'd like to integrate logger package with multithreading. And I don't want to investigate logger's internals if someone else has already done this work.

Comment: @Andrey, it seems you did not get my idea. What I proposed is not to integrate logger package with multithreading, but rather to leverage the Tcl's way to do multithreading to make logger not be concerned with multithreading at all. I've updated my post with a working program demonstrating the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

[A Logging API for Tcl](http://code.activestate.com/lists/tcl-core/10866/)

This implementation is thread safe. Because of the general
purpose the C-functions do not require a tcl-interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Where can I find links to downloadable archive and documentation? Should I contact to developer by his email?

Comment: @bilash.saha, that's for the "logger" package from Tcllib. I was asking about that tcl-core post in fact ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "multithreading" wrapper for `logger` package:

```
# replacement for logger::init procedure from logger package
proc ::mylogger::init { service } {
  set log [logger::init $service]

  foreach lvl [logger::levels] {
    interp alias {} log_to_file_$lvl {} ::mylogger::log $lvl $service
    ${log}::logproc $lvl log_to_file_$lvl
  }

  return $log
}

proc mylogger::server { } {
  set t [thread::create {

    proc log { level txt } {
        set msg "\[[clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"]\]\t$level\t$txt"
        puts stderr $msg
    }

    # enter to event loop
    thread::wait
  }]

  tsv::set measure-logger loggerThread $t
}

proc ::mylogger::log { level service txt } {
  set t [tsv::get measure-logger loggerThread]
  thread::send -async $t [list log $level "$service\t$txt"]
}

# EXAMPLE

# start logging thread
# should be called once from main application thread
::mylogger::server

# create logger
# may be called from any thread
set log [mylogger::init myservice]

# log a message
# may be called from the thread the "mylogger::init myservice" was called in
${log}::debug myservice "Hello, World!"

# wait a second
after 1000
```

Comment: Probably Works. The `tsv::get` approach in `::mylogger:log` looks a bit dubious, i would simply create a custom proc with the right thread id embedded instead of calling the `tsv::get` on each logging call. Easiest way to do that would be in the `::mylogger::init` proc where you setup the logging aliases anyway, you could simply add the thread id as a fixed 4th parameter to the alias.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you want to achieve with a multithreaded use of logger.

If you just have the use case to not block your worker threads while writing log messages to disk, the simplest way is to use logger normally and configure a simple logproc that does a thread::send -async to some logging thread (which might itself use logger with appenders to write the actual log files) with your log message (basically what has been sketched in the accepted answer).

If you want to use loggers option to disable/enable logging for the whole program, across various threads, you need to do a little more work to propagate loglevel changes to all threads via custom lvlchangeproc's.